# Is .env fallback evaluated even though the value is set?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.3

Given the following line:

```
env('AN_ENV_KEY', file_exists('my\path') ? 'value' : 'other-value');
```

Is the fallback evaluated even though the `AN_ENV_KEY` is specified in the `.env` file?

I'm asking this because in my server, after the project update, one of the dependencies added a similar line in its changes and now the deployment fails even though I specified the `AN_ENV_KEY=value` due to some permission issues with the `file_exists()` part

I'm just curious of this given that my assumption is that if the value is set then the fallback should be omitted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share more details? "The deployment fails" sounds like you could debug whatever happens

Comment: where are you doing this `env` call?

Comment: Sure, the error is this ```file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.``` but I get it given that the fallback ```file_exists(...)``` is causing the issue. What I don't get is why it reaches that part of the code when the `AN_ENV_KEY` value is set in the `.env`

Comment: @lagbox the call is done by a dependency. I reached that line while debugging the deployment error.

Comment: where in the dependency, in a config file? if they are doing it out of a config file and you cached your config then the '.env' does not get loaded

Comment: @lagbox yes, in a config file from the dependency. You can check it [here](https://github.com/Silvanite/brandenburg/blob/41625a3052acccc3ad9b6d2505e16cdcb6de3aa6/src/Config/brandenburg.php#L7).

Comment: well that isn't the same KEY

Comment: @lagbox mate I used just generic code for the question, of course I set the proper key in project

Comment: well stop showing us random stuff and show us your real stuff :) but your assumption is correct, it is supposed to work that way

Comment: Please share more context - if that is something from within your application, then yes, the method `env` might get called with whatever input you specify - but IMO this does not relate in an terms to Laravel, but to basic concepts of programming: wherever you call a function, you call a function. Whether it is evaluated to whatever you expect is a completely different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining this env variable you should alter this config file. There are 2 arguments passed to `env` here and all of them must be resolved as they are being passed to a function. This is before the function even runs, so it doesn't matter if that env variable exists that `file_exists` call will happen no matter what.

You can remove the expression which uses `file_exists` as its unneeded in your case since you are setting the env variable.

```
env('USER_MODEL', 'some sane default?');
```

This is fine since you are supposed to publish this config file so its in your application config, so you control it at this point.

**Part 2**

Now that your version of the config file is fixed we don't want the package's config file to be merged since it will still try to do this `file_exists` call every time. To do this we will extend their provider and override the `register` method. Then we will add your version of their provider to the providers list and also tell the auto discovery system to ignore this package (so it doesn't register its provider or alias):

`app/Providers/SomeCoolNamedProvider`:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Silvanite\Brandenburg\Providers\BrandenburgServiceProvider;

class SomeCoolNamedProvider extends BrandenburgServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        // in their version they merge the config here
        // but we don't want that, so leave this blank
    }
}
```

`config/app.php`:

```
$providers = [
    ...
    App\Providers\SomeCoolNamedProvider::class,
];

$aliases = [
    ...
    'BrandenburgPolicy' => Silvanite\Brandenburg\Facades\PolicyFacade::class,
];
```

`composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "silvanite/brandenburg"
        ]
    }
},
```

You can run the auto discovery command after this, `php artisan package:discover`

Comment: I have it like that after the config has been published but it still tries to use the package config file. Very weird

Comment: right because their config file is still being loaded, no matter what ... since i think it is silly what they are dong in their config file I would override their provider to not merge their config file ... if you want i can give you an example how to do that

Comment: @KennyHorna alright give that update a go

Comment: Yep, I'm deploying that. Will update when it finishes

Comment: it might still fail because it will want to load that provide when you run artisan ... if that is the case the file that holds that information will have to be removed  `bootstrap/cache/packages.json` then you can run auto discovery

Comment: It worked, cache is cleared after each deployment. I added the `registerPolicy()` code in the boot just in case but now it's  been deployed. Thanks for the help

Comment: no problem, don't override anything else though, just leave that provider how it is because they are doing more than just calling `registerPolicy` in the boot method ... good luck with your project ... hopefully this made sense   `:)`

Comment: Yes I will try to look into the package code later and see if I can make a PR to address it because for some reason the config values are not merged with the published ones and keep relying in the package config file. Anyway, issue solved at the moment at least. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

No, the fallback is not evaluated if the value is found inside the `.env` file. If the value is set, then it is returned.

You can see that by [checking the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Env.php#L97) on Github.

Comment: yes the fallback is evaluated, it is an expression as an argument to a function, all the expressions are resolved since they need to be passed to the function